# How to write in a formal way the division by (dφ)²

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, differential

**Question:** Consider a conic surface defined by: \begin{equation} z = h \left( 1-\frac{\rho}{a} \right) , \rho = \sqrt{x²+y²} \end{equation}
generated by the revolution of the line \begin{equation} z = h \left( 1-\frac{y}{a} \right) , y \geq 0 \end{equation} we want to find the curve with the smallest distance on the conic surface between two points \begin{equation} A(0,-a,0), B(0,a,0) \end{equation}.
a) Find the possible functional f, in cylindrical coordinates where:
\begin{equation} f(\phi,\phi' \equiv \frac{d\phi}{d\rho},\rho)\end{equation}
where $\rho$ is the independent variable on f. Define $\beta$ as $\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{h}{a}\right)^2}$, that must appear on f.

**What i did:**

Let $ds$ be the distance function in cylindrical coordinates where $(ds)^2 = (dz)^2 + (d\rho)^2 + \rho^2 (d\phi)^2$

We know that: $\frac{dz}{d\rho} = -\frac{h}{a}d\rho$

Then

$(ds)^2 = (dz)^² + (d\rho)^2 + \rho^2 (d\phi)^2 \implies (ds)^2 = \left( -\frac{h}{a}d\rho \right)^2 + (d\rho)^2 + \rho^2 (d\phi)^2 \implies ds = \left( 1 + \frac{h}{a}\right)^2(d\rho)^2 + \rho^2 (d\phi)^2$ Substituting $\beta$ in the equation we have:

\begin{equation*}
  (ds)² =  \beta² (d\rho)²  + (\rho)²( d\varphi )² \implies \left(\dfrac{ds}{d\rho}\right)^2 = (\beta)² + (\rho)²\left(\dfrac{d\varphi}{d\rho}\right)^2
\end{equation*}

**My question:**
I read many topics in this subject about why divide or multiply by differential is wrong. And thought that really understood, but i don't know how to apply the right way. I was doing a physics question and the final steps as mentioned that i did was:

\begin{equation*}
  (ds)² =  \beta² (d\rho)²  + (\rho)²( d\varphi )² \implies \left(\dfrac{ds}{d\rho}\right)^2 = (\beta)² + (\rho)²\left(\dfrac{d\varphi}{d\rho}\right)^2
\end{equation*}

I would like to write my solution more detailed and mathematically formal. How can i write these steps more detailed and mathematically formal (with rigor of the differentials)?

Edit:Following @PawełCzyż suggestion, i'm adding all the question to get some context.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\dfrac{ds}{d\rho}\right)^2$?

Comment: Oh yes, i  corrected, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps replacing the $d$'s with $\Delta$'s, and then limiting to zero will work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the context? Is $\beta$ a constant? What do you do with $(ds/d\rho)^2$ afterwards? Also, posting here the question you are solving with this formula may help us :)

Comment: Added the question for more context.

Comment: From your first line, $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}\rho} = -h/a$.  Why, in the second line of "What I did", do you have "$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}\rho} = +(h/a) \,\mathrm{d}\rho$"?

Comment: i forgot to write the minus signal, corrected, thanks. I elevated to square and put in evidence $d\rho^2$

Comment: Your $d^2$ notation throughout is incorrect.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, Corrected!